# How to concat a 2-d tensor with a 3-d tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, concatenation

In AE-lstm, 
here is a lstm out with shape `[batch, timestamp, diml]`(regarded as `[b, t, dl]`) and the aspect vector is `[batch, dima]` (regarded as `[b, da]`)

> How to concat two variables to make the shape be `[b, t, dl+da]`?

It means that for every batch, concat the aspect vector to every timestamp row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure, but I think what you want is

```
C = tf.concat([A, tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(B, axis=1), [1, t, 1])], axis=-1)
```

where `A` is your lstm and `B` the aspect vector. I validated it by simply checking the dimensions, which seems to be correct. Let's see if this is what you actually need.

**Edit**: Just to be clear, this is the entire code I used to test this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

b = 5
t = 10
dl = 15
da = 12

A = tf.ones(shape=(b, t, dl))
B = tf.ones(shape=(b, da))

C = tf.concat([A, tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(B, axis=1), [1, t, 1])], axis=-1)
print(C)
```

Which gives the expected output:

```
Tensor("concat:0", shape=(5, 10, 27), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: You're Right! tf.tile() replicate it so it's now easy to concat. Thanks again!